# Saving CFA array data as DNG

Tags: image-processing, dng, dcraw

I'm looking for a simple method (preferably C/C++/Python or even a shell command) to save RAW CFA data from array to a DNG file.

Something that would be like the following example 
 in android https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/DngCreator but for a Linux machine

Comment: Why do you want a DNG file specifically? Do you have all the calibration and profiling data necessary?

Comment: [Here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6534/how-can-i-convert-a-proprietary-raw-image-format-to-adobe-dng) is the leading answer. I tried to manually create a DNG sample image according to the DNG documentation. It's very difficult  to set all the exif data correctly.

Comment: I'm tuning an existing ISP that receives a DNG file, I have another camera that creates DNGs and I'm looking into adding the other camera sensor that I have that sends RAW CFA.
I have the camera parameters/registers in hand when for the metada

Comment: These may help... http://openendedgroup.com/field/GigECamerasAndField and also https://github.com/apertus-open-source-cinema/CMV12000_DNG_Writer

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it and let you know if I was able to solve it